# How can I change the IAM role assignments of a azure storage account via REST?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How am I able to change the IAM of an azure storage account via REST? I would like to change the IAM of a specific storage account. I would like to add a role assignment to a managed identity, and later on remove it via REST. I can do that easily by clicking in the portal, but I would like to do it more programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Assign Azure roles using the REST API

1. Use the Role Definitions - List REST API or see Built-in roles to get the identifier for the role definition you want to assign.
2. Use a GUID tool to generate a unique identifier that will be used for the role assignment identifier. The identifier has the format: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
3. Start with the following request and body:

`PUT https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/{roleAssignmentId}?api-version=2015-07-01`

```
{
   "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/{roleDefinitionId}",
    "principalId": "{principalId}"
  }
}
```

4. Within the URI, replace {scope} with the scope for the role assignment.
5. Replace {roleAssignmentId} with the GUID identifier of the role assignment.

6 Within the request body, replace {scope} with the scope for the role assignment.

7. Replace {roleDefinitionId} with the role definition identifier.
8. Replace {principalId} with the object identifier of the user, group, or service principal that will be assigned the role.

More details: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest